# Float divs with variable heights (arrange)

Tags: css, html, css-float

I'm having a simple problem concerning the arrangement of floating divs with variables heights.

The goal:

[image: goal]

The result:

[image: result]

I just have div containers with css float: left; and no height defined. The first red circle indicated that my technique fails, although the second one proves me wrong by showing it IS working. Unfortunately, the last (not on screenshots) just starts floating after the height of the previous one (so there's a whole empty space on the left).

How should i solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: The result (image): http://i.imgur.com/FkGsB.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that this is doable a 100% with "just" css, but jquery-masonry should do the trick [ http://desandro.com/resources/jquery-masonry/ ]. Well, but i hope somebody proofs me wrong :)

Comment: Hey, thanks! Never heard of that. If i can do it with jquery, i'll leave the css :-)

Comment: if it works out the way you want ... an Answer accepted and/or up-vote would be much appreciated :D (btw. i use it for my tumblr page, works just dandy)

Answer (score 0):

You have two columns. Then code it accordingly:

```
<div class="column">
    contents of first column
</div>
<div class="column">
    contents of second column
</div>
```

(you set float:left on the column DIVs)

Comment: I have more than 2, but he's talking about the columns Hannes. So this solution WOULD be good, except for the fact that this websites will be a .NET database website which makes the use of static columns a problem. It would be a hassle making the columns fill up with content dynamically. But thanks anyway!

Comment: The layout presented in the first image consists of two independent columns.